# Use StringTemplate with Grails domain class as model

Tags: grails, stringtemplate

Can I use Grails Domain Classes as Model for ST (StringTemplate) library.

e.g.

```
String content = "Hello {personInstance.first_name}!"
char startChar = '{'
char endChar = '}'
ST st = new ST(content, startChar, endChar)
st.add("personInstance", personInstance)
st.render()
```

What I get back from the render is simply "Hello ".
Should that work or do I need to write an adapter to use Grails Domain classes as Model for ST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your Person domainClass, I ques you meant {personInstance.firstName} instead of {personInstance.first_name}. 
ST supports accessing properties.